# Difference between @property (nonatomic, readonly) and @property inside class extension?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

I have an Objective-c class "MyClass". In MyClass.m I have a class extension that declares a `CGFloat` property:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat myFloat;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myFloat;
//...
@end
```

**What changes (if anything) when the property is declared using the `readonly` keyword?**

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat myFloat;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myFloat;
//...
@end
```

Perhaps in the first case I can say `self.myFloat = 123.0;` and `CGFloat f = self.myFloat;` inside MyClass? Then in the second case the `readonly` keyword prevents the assignment `self.myFloat = 123.0;` but allows the read `CGFloat f = self.myFloat;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option `readonly` means that only the getter method is being declared for this property. Thus, without a setter, it can't be modified via `myObject.myFloat=0.5f;`

If you don't declare it `readonly`, it's `read write` by default.

Declaring your property via () extension does not modify the access mode but it modifies the scope; it will be a "private" property.

Answer (score 3):

`@synthesize` uses the `@property` definition to generate the appropiate getter/setter for the iVar. When you specify `readonly`, no setter is generated. This is not strictly enforced as you can write your own setter if you choose (though that doesn't make a ton of sense).

Declaring the property in a category simply defines the scope of the property to be within that category.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, declaring your property as  `readonly` you tell compiler to not generate setter method automatically and so `self.myFloat = 123.0;` will be illegal (unless you create that method manually).